# Is it possible to use HangFire without the Dashboard and Server options?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, hangfire

I have an asp.net core MVC site where I need to use hangfire, then I have a hangfire server.

I need to use the hangfire dashboard only on the server. But if I don't use the app.UseHangfireDashboard(), the following exception happens.

Code

```
var configuration = builder.Configuration;
var hangfireConnectionStrings = configuration.GetConnectionString("Hangfire");
builder.Services.AddHangfire(conf =>
{
    conf.UseSqlServerStorage(hangfireConnectionStrings);
    conf.UseHangfireMediatR();
});
```

Exception

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Current JobStorage instance has not been initialized yet. You must set it before using Hangfire Client or Server API. For .NET Core applications please call the `IServiceCollection.AddHangfire` extension method from Hangfire.NetCore or Hangfire.AspNetCore package depending on your application type when configuring the services and ensure service-based APIs are used instead of static ones, like `IBackgroundJobClient` instead of `BackgroundJob` and `IRecurringJobManager` instead of `RecurringJob`.
```

I understand that it happened because there is some configuration pending, but I couldn't find any way to use hangfire without calling `UseHangfireDashboard` or `AddHangfireServer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it by creating this extension, the most important line here is

```
var gc = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IGlobalConfiguration>();
```

I understand that it initialize the service.

```
public static class HangfireExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseHangfire(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(app, nameof(app));
        var gc = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IGlobalConfiguration>();
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(gc, nameof(gc));
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(JobStorage.Current, nameof(JobStorage.Current));

        return app;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is pretty shitty that this exception occurs because of not using dashboard. Thanks for the detective work done here!